# Testing dynamic URL in bundler application with cucumber/capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

I am using a Cucumber-Capybara combination for testing. I am not using Rails application but a simple bundler application.

I want to test some dynamic URLs for my front-end application. For example, the URL for item-show page is:

```
/suitability/items/197/
(Assertion: Then I go to suitability-item-show page)
```

In the above URL, 197 is an :id. I want to test similar pages which contains dynamic data.

I have tried following two ways:

```
Then(/^I should be on suitability\-item\-show page$/) do
   visit '/suitability/items/:id/'
end
```

and

```
Then(/^I should be on suitability\-item\-show page$/) do
  visit "/suitability/items/#{:id}/"
end
```

But they didn't work out for me

Please help me with the solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

If var="id", then 
visit "/suitability/items/#{var}/"
should work.
I'm not getting how u got ':id'...can u throw some more light on that

Comment: The reason behind writing :id is that I am trying to write the URL as we mention it in routes file. I tried your solution. I am getting "undefined local variable or method `id'" error.